# jQuery load() images from different page and use them in script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, jquery-load

I want to use the load() function from jQuery to get images from address, for example load-images.php

`load-images.php` looks like:

```
<div id="smth">

    <p><img src="images/test1.jpg" /></p>
    <p><img src="images/test2.jpg" /></p>
    <p><img src="images/test3.jpg" /></p>
    <p><img src="images/test4.jpg" /></p>
    <p><img src="images/test5.jpg" /></p>
    <p><img src="images/test6.jpg" /></p>
    <p><img src="images/test7.jpg" /></p>
    <p><img src="images/test8.jpg" /></p>
    <p><img src="images/test9.jpg" /></p>
    <p><img src="images/test10.jpg" /></p>

</div>
```

- [**JSFIDDLE** - load-images.php](http://jsfiddle.net/744Ew/)

I need to make a function that reads all images from file `load-images.php` and use them in slider script ([Basic jQuery Slider](http://www.basic-slider.com/)). I want loaded images use in slider.

**Here is LIVE DEMOS**:
1) http://spijay.com/demo/stackoverflow-01.05.2014/load-images.php
2) http://fiddle.jshell.net/744Ew/show/ (same demo in jsfiddle.net for making working example)

So far i made this code:

- [**JSFIDDLE** - JavaScript load()](http://jsfiddle.net/YK3Ud/4/)

Comment: Any reason why you need them in an external PHP page and can't reference them in Javascript instead?

Comment: I have lots of pages such as load-images.php ~ about 190.
I think that reading images by load() is faster. I do not have time to do 190 new pages, which I will include - unless you suggest something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used a different slider [Cycle2](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/) but try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

setTimeout(function() {

    $('#loading').fadeOut(400, function() {

        $(this).remove();

        $('#container').load('http://fiddle.jshell.net/744Ew/show/ img', function() {

            $('#container').cycle({  speed: 600 });

        });

    });

}, 1000);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/47FP2/9/

Comment: Works nice! Q1. Can I somehow call a single image? Something like response [0] in load() callback ? Q2. How to speed up slides ?

Comment: you could use `img:first` so `.load('http://fiddle.jshell.net/744Ew/show/ img:first` or `:nth-child(3n+0)` to get s specifc image

Comment: or you could target via class `.load('http://fiddle.jshell.net/744Ew/show/' + ' .img-class')` hvent test anything but a good starting point

Comment: thanks! And have u any advice how to speed up slides ?

Comment: @PatrykSzram Just change the `speed: 600` to whatever speed you wise. For more options see: [Cycle2](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/). I removed the manual speed from my answer by the way. Save confusion.

Comment: @PatrykSzram if your happy with answer - Please accept it. Thanks